# Removing double qoute in json_encode / PHP

Tags: php, json, string

I need some help with JSON and PHP. Here's my code in PHP:

```
include 'class.Connection.php';

$branch = $_GET["b"];   
$records = array();

$sqlNailDisplay = "SELECT NAD_ID FROM tbl_NailArtDesign WHERE NAD_Available = 1";
$query0 = mysql_query($sqlNailDisplay) or die(mysql_error());
while($rSet0 = mysql_fetch_array($query0, MYSQL_BOTH)) {

    $actualPrice = 0.00;
$nailart = $rSet0["NAD_ID"];
//please note, &#123; is the ascii code for '{', &#125; is the ascii code for '}', while &#34; is the ascii code for '"'
$mergedData = "&#123;&#34;NAD_ID&#34;:&#34;".$nailart."&#34;,&#34;";

//individual nail art details
$sqlNailArt = "SELECT * FROM tbl_NailArtDesign WHERE NAD_ID = '".$nailart."' AND NAD_Available = 1";
$query1 = mysql_query($sqlNailArt) or die(mysql_error());
while($rSet1 = mysql_fetch_array($query1, MYSQL_BOTH)) {
    $NAD_Ext = $rSet1["NAD_Ext"];
    $CC_ID = $rSet1["CC_ID"];
    $CT_ID = $rSet1["CT_ID"];
    $CST_ID = $rSet1["CST_ID"];
    if(empty($CST_ID)) {
    $CST_ID = "null";
    }
    $NAD_Descrip = $rSet1["NAD_Descrip"];

    $mergedData = $mergedData."NAD_Ext&#34;:&#34;".$NAD_Ext."&#34;,&#34;CC_ID&#34;:&#34;".$CC_ID."&#34;,&#34;CT_ID&#34;:&#34;".$CT_ID."&#34;,&#34;CST_ID&#34;:&#34;".$CST_ID."&#34;,&#34;NAD_Descrip&#34;:&#34;".$NAD_Descrip."&#34;,&#34;";
    }

//product used and price details
$sqlProductsUsed = "SELECT PL_ID FROM tbl_ProductUsed WHERE NAD_ID = '".$nailart."'";
$query2 = mysql_query($sqlProductsUsed) or die(mysql_error());
while($rSet2 = mysql_fetch_array($query2, MYSQL_BOTH)) {
    $PL_ID = $rSet2["PL_ID"];
    $sqlProductPrice = "SELECT PP_Amount FROM tbl_ProductPrice WHERE PL_ID = ".$PL_ID." AND BL_ID = '".$branch."'";
    $query3 = mysql_query($sqlProductPrice) or die(mysql_error());
    while($rSet3 = mysql_fetch_array($query3, MYSQL_BOTH)) {
    $price = number_format($rSet3["PP_Amount"],2);
    $actualPrice = number_format($actualPrice + $price,2);
    }           
    $mergedData = $mergedData."PL_ID&#34;:&#34;".$PL_ID."&#34;,&#34;PP_Amount&#34;:&#34;".$price."&#34;,&#34;";
}
$mergedData = $mergedData."NAD_Price&#34;:&#34;".$actualPrice."&#34;&#125;";

$records[] = $mergedData;

} mysql_free_result($query0);

echo json_encode($records);
```

And this is the result I'm getting:

```
["{"NAD_ID":"ND0001","NAD_Ext":"jpg","CC_ID":"1","CT_ID":"1","CST_ID":"null","NAD_Descrip":"Giving you the aquatic feeling with Turquoise Marble","PL_ID":"1","PP_Amount":"9.00","PL_ID":"2","PP_Amount":"9.10","PL_ID":"3","PP_Amount":"9.00","NAD_Price":"27.10"}","{"NAD_ID":"ND0002","NAD_Ext":"jpg","CC_ID":"1","CT_ID":"1","CST_ID":"null","NAD_Descrip":"Add a twirl in your life with Lavender Twirl","PL_ID":"1","PP_Amount":"9.00","PL_ID":"2","PP_Amount":"9.10","PL_ID":"3","PP_Amount":"9.00","NAD_Price":"27.10"}"]
```

I need my result to look like this:

```
[{"NAD_ID":"ND0001","NAD_Ext":"jpg","CC_ID":"1","CT_ID":"1","CST_ID":"null","NAD_Descrip":"Giving you the aquatic feeling with Turquoise Marble","PL_ID":"1","PP_Amount":"9.00","PL_ID":"2","PP_Amount":"9.10","PL_ID":"3","PP_Amount":"9.00","NAD_Price":"27.10"},{"NAD_ID":"ND0002","NAD_Ext":"jpg","CC_ID":"1","CT_ID":"1","CST_ID":"null","NAD_Descrip":"Add a twirl in your life with Lavender Twirl","PL_ID":"1","PP_Amount":"9.00","PL_ID":"2","PP_Amount":"9.10","PL_ID":"3","PP_Amount":"9.00","NAD_Price":"27.10"}]
```

There an extra double quotes that I need to remove from my output.

[**"**{" , **"**,**"** , }**"**]

Please help, I'm already at my limit and I already did searching for this, and I can't seem to get any resolution for this...

Comment: I'm able to remove the extra double quotes (thanks to @ailvenge), but the output is not being read in xcode...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hardcoded method:

```
$result = "[".substr(json_encode($records), 2, -2)."]";
$result = str_replace('","', ',', $result);
```

Comment: in what part should I add that?

Comment: Instead of `echo json_encode($records);` and then `echo $result;`.

Comment: Yes, I'm able to remove the double quotes for ["{ and }"]. Thank you very much! Now, the double quotes that I need to remove is '","' . it should only be ',' e.g.

"NAD_Price":"27.10"}","{"NAD_ID":"ND0002"

it should be 

"NAD_Price":"27.10"},{"NAD_ID":"ND0002"